# Adding a button in linear layout crashes

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I really do not understand why this simple code crashes in this line `layout.addView(button);`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setHeight(100);
    button.setWidth(100);
    button.setText("HELLO");
    button.setLayoutParams(p);
    layout.addView(button);
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
edited code still crushes. But now crushes in setContentView.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    setContentView(layout); 
    LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    int i,j;
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setHeight(100);
    button.setWidth(100);
    button.setText("HELLO");
    layout.addView(button,p);
```

Logcat report
[image]

Comment: you have to call setContentView BEFORE findViewById not AFTER

Comment: Then how am I gonna give the `layout` as argument in setContentView? I have to get it from the xml first right by doing findViewById?

Comment: can't you simply do setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) ?

Comment: Thanks blackbelt it works :) But suppose activity_main.xml had two or three layouts. And I wanted to get only one of them as my layout for the activity. how can I do that?

Comment: I am glad it works. your question does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply because you haven't called `setContentView()`. The root `View` of your `Activity` is `null`, so is `layout`.

Comment: @kalkin, You need to call setContentView() before doing any findViewById() calls.

Comment: usually the call looks like `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)`, the value of the `layout` variable is probably not a valid layout id

Comment: but I added that id in the activity_main.xml. And if I do `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)` then after that how am I gonna access yourlayout from java code so that later I can add buttons and stuff in it?

Comment: This is just example code. You better read some basics on how android works - maybe here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the `Views` width height here:

```
button.setHeight(100);
button.setWidth(100);
```

then immediately overwriting it:

```
button.setLayoutParams(p);
```

try this, remove the `setWidth` and `setLayoutParams` and remove `p`:

```
  layout.addView(button, new LayoutParams(100,100));
```

Comment: Hi I edited as you mentioned. But it crushes in the setContentView. thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry, missed one of your lines in the question

Comment: ... Ah.. "Crushes" - you mean "Crashes" I thought the button was being crushed. :)